# Vue reactive properties on dynamically created DOM elements

Tags: javascript, vue.js, dom, vuejs2, createelement

I was toying with Vue 2 and I tried to create DOM elements in the `mounted` hook like so:

```
<div id="app">
  <div id="container">
    <label for="static_name">Existing field</label>
    <input type="text"
           id="static_name"
           v-model="value">
  </div>
</div>

<script>
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    value: 'Example value'
  },
  mounted: function() {
    const container = document.getElementById('container')
    const label = document.createElement('label') 
    const input = document.createElement('input')
    
    label.setAttribute("for", "name")
    label.innerHTML = "Added field"
    input.setAttribute("type", "text")
    input.setAttribute("id", "name")
    input.setAttribute("v-model", "value")  // I would use reactivity here
    container.append(label)
    container.append(input)
  }
})
</script>
```

[JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/1auwzLcy/3/)

The "Added field" input field created in the `mounted` hook replicates the "Existing field" in the html code but the `v-model` directive does not work in the former (while it works in the field defined in the html code). I think this is because reactive data is processed in the creation phase of the life cycle.

**My question is:** is there a way (workaround) to use reactive data in DOM elements added with the `createElement` API as in the example?

I am using Vue 2 but I am eager to move to Vue 3 if needed.

Comment: Just do not do that. This isn't how Vue is supposed to be used. v-model is a directive, not an attribute, it doesn't make sense in the context of DOM element

Answer (score 0):

Use vue 2.7, or vue 2.6 with composition api, or vue 3
Then add a reactive or ref value.

```
const model = ref('hello')
setAttribute('v-model', model)

watch(model, value=>{
})
```

You will need to access your value outside the watcher or template using `model.value`.

It might make more sense to dynamically create a new Vue component though.